# Sorted insertion using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a code similar to this (rendering information from external service):

```
var myList =  {'id1' : {prop1:'v1', prop2:'v2'}, 
               'id2' : {prop1:'v3', prop2:'v4'}}; 

for (var k in myList) {
    var html = '<div id="xxx">stuff</div>';
    html.data('item', myList[k]);
    $('#parentDiv').append(html);
}
```

As I can't rely on ordering when using `for (x in y)` I want to insert the elements in a specific position, let's say ordered by `prop1`.

So, how can I change the append to an insert after the element whose `prop1` is immediately lesser than the actual element being inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use an array:

```
var myList =  {'id1' : {prop1:'v1', prop2:'v2'}, 
               'id2' : {prop1:'v30', prop2:'v4'},
               'id3' : {prop1:'v13', prop2:'v4'}},
    sorted = []; 

for (var k in myList) {
    sorted.push(myList[k]);
}
sorted.sort(function (a,b) {
 return a.prop1 > b.prop1;   
});

for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    var html = '<div id="xxx">stuff</div>';
    html.data('item', sorted[i]);
    $('#parentDiv').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to sort them first?

```
tmpList = [] // turn myList to array
tmpList.sort(function (a, b) { return a.prop1 > b.prop1});
// turn tmpList to dict
```